# Remove 1 Duplicate row from SQL Table if two column data matches

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three columns in my table

KeyName,
Number,
Data

The data consist of lot of duplicate entries. I need to delete the 1 row from each of the duplicate entries in the table if the "KeyName" and "Data" are repeated.
How shall I achieve this is SQL Query .

Comment: what is your rdbms?  Sql Server, Postgres, Mysql ....?

Comment: What if there are more than two duplicates?

Comment: Mine is SQL server. I have only few entries which are more than two duplicates. Which i thought of deleting manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it

```
WITH CTE
    AS (SELECT KeyName
            , Number
            , Data
            , [rn] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY KeyName
                                          , Data ORDER BY KeyName
                                                     , Data)
        FROM   yourtable)
     /* UNCOMMENT BELOW TO DELETE */
     --DELETE
    --FROM   CTE
    --WHERE  rn > 1;

    SELECT *
    FROM   CTE
    WHERE  rn > 1;
```

Comment: This worked thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can keep one row for each pair by using `row_number()`:

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by keyname, data order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from t
     )
delete
from todelete
where seqnum > 1;
```

As with any such operation, you should check first before deleting.  This is easy:

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by keyname, data order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from t
     )
select *
from todelete
where seqnum > 1;
```

Comment: Just received correct answer as yours. Sorry stackoverflow doesnt allow two answers to be marked as correct .Thank you for your response

Comment: @arun . . . The decision of which answer to accept is wholly up to the OP.